# Get live stream api of my periscope

Tags: api

I want to integrate my periscope account so that whenever I am making video, it will automatically live stream onto my website.

I have a account at https://www.periscope.tv/ where i want live stream to display on my website using the periscope api, is it possible to make it run successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try but i'm sure that it work fine!
Look this [https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-use-the-public-periscope-stream-api-8dfedc7fe872#.8xy2porcu]

Comment: This is link only answer. Please add more details to answer

Comment: I have completed this project by help of mentioned link :)

Comment: even i am also looking for the same , but did not find any example of using  periscope api for android , if anyone have , please guide me?